# Google sheets API Batch Update

Tags: java, google-sheets, batch-updates

Could someone please post an example of using Google's batchUpdateValuesRequest to set multiple value on a google sheet?

I am just trying to understand how to change values in a google sheet.

I can successfully authenticate (and read data from a sheet) but am having trouble formatting the update request and its data.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check https://github.com/gsuitedevs/java-samples/blob/master/sheets/snippets/src/main/java/SpreadsheetSnippets.java

Comment: and https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Comment: In which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets

Examples of batch updates can be seen on the link above.

```
public BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse batchUpdate(String spreadsheetId, String title,
                                                  String find, String replacement)
        throws IOException {
    Sheets service = this.service;
    // [START sheets_batch_update]
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    // Change the spreadsheet's title.
    requests.add(new Request()
            .setUpdateSpreadsheetProperties(new UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest()
                    .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                            .setTitle(title))
                    .setFields("title")));
    // Find and replace text.
    requests.add(new Request()
            .setFindReplace(new FindReplaceRequest()
                    .setFind(find)
                    .setReplacement(replacement)
                    .setAllSheets(true)));
    // Add additional requests (operations) ...

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body =
            new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response =
            service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
    FindReplaceResponse findReplaceResponse = response.getReplies().get(1).getFindReplace();
    System.out.printf("%d replacements made.", findReplaceResponse.getOccurrencesChanged());
    // [END sheets_batch_update]
    return response;
}
```

Comment: The link is dead - This is a good example of where an example pasted would be nice

Comment: apologies! I have updated the answer with the code